# Encoding method used for the SSO saml request/data in the our application got depreciated

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

We are using UTF8 encoding method to encode the SSO saml request/data in the our application and it was working fine. But suddenly the SSO functionality stopped working and on analysis we found that the encoding method used got depreciated.

Previous code which stopped working:

```
new DeflaterOutputStream(output)
```

Updated code which fixed the issue:

```
new DeflaterOutputStream(output, 
    new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Deflater(
     level: ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
     noZlibHeaderOrFooter: true)))
```

So basically we had updated the DeflaterOutputStream to use DEFLATE and suppressed the header and footer to fix the issue.

Can some one tell when the old DeflaterOutputStream code got depreciated. We need to understand why the previous working code stopped working suddenly.

Thanks for all you help.

Comment: Have you tried reading SharpZipLib's release notes or checking [the Github repo](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib)? The constructor [is *not* deprecated or missing anyway](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/Compression/Streams/DeflaterOutputStream.cs#L23), so it's unclear what the problem is. In any case, only the authors can answer why they made any specific change. Major changes are almost certainly documented in the release notes and Github repo issues